# Display related historical data alongside current data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to display some data and its related historical data if available. The data is pulled from two tables, i.e. Job details and Job problems

For example: In Job details table i have columns for job id, client, job problems and job history id whereas in job problems table i have job id and job problems columns. The two tables are linked by the job id field.

If a client returns, the job history id field is updated with the most recent job id from the cients' previous visit.

I want to write a query to display details for the current job as well as the job history problems during the clients last visit (if history is available).

How do i achieve that?

I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: I know you've mostly described what your table looks like, but I think it'll be still benefical to post the actual table structure in the question.

Comment: also, I'd advice you to take and make a example of the result you want. maybe make a fake table in the question showing which column you want and in what format.

Comment: Thanks Jacky Cheng, kindly advice how i can post a table, currently unable to edit the question